# How to wait until meteor subscription data is fully complete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor

I've been looking through a lot of questions/answers as well as the meteor docs but am still having trouble with meteor react and waiting until the subscription's data is completely loaded. I'm trying to do two differen't things, one if the array recieved from the database is less than an array created clientside, and then do something else if it is bigger or equal.

The issue is with my subscription, data is being piped in a bit at time, so the first statement will always trigger atleast once.

I was wondering if there was a way to make sure all the data from the database has come through, before calling a function.

```
 if (import.length < arrayLength) {
      ...
 }
 if (import.length > arrayLength || import.length === arrayLength) {
      ...
 }
```

full code example below

```
import { DropzoneDialog } from "material-ui-dropzone";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { Cards } from "../../../../both/collections";
import { withTracker } from "meteor/react-meteor-data";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import _, { map, object } from 'underscore';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  importButton: {
    color: "#C8C8C8",
    borderColor: "#C8C8C8",
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: "rgba(72,72,72,0.7)",
      borderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255)",
      color: "rgba(255, 255, 255)",
    },
  },
});

function importDeck(files, setDeckIsReady, setDeckLength, setCountObj, sub, setSubscription) {

  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsText(files[0]);

  reader.onload = function () {
    let cardArray = reader.result.split("\n");
    let cardArrayFiltered = cardArray.filter(Boolean)
    const countObj = cardArrayFiltered.reduce((acc, next) => {
      count = next.substr(0, next.indexOf(' ')); 
      name = next.substr(next.indexOf(' ') + 1); 
      return {...acc, [name]: count}
    }, {});
    sub.stop()
    const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('cardSearchTwo', Object.keys(countObj), {onReady() {setDeckIsReady(true)}})
    setDeckLength(Object.keys(countObj).length)
    setCountObj(countObj) 
    setSubscription(subscription)
  };
}

export function DeckImport({importCards, setCurrentDeck, importDeckFinal, search, setSearch}) {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [deckIsReady, setDeckIsReady] = useState(false);
  const [deckLength, setDeckLength] = useState(0);
  const [countObj, setCountObj] = useState({});
  const [subscription, setSubscription] = useState({stop(){}})
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false)
  console.log(deckIsReady, importCards)
  let missingCards = []
  let fixedDeck = importCards
  useEffect(() => {
    if (importCards.length < deckLength && deckIsReady) {
      fixedDeck = []
      Object.keys(countObj).forEach(card => {
        if (!importCards.some(e => e.name === card)) missingCards.push(card)
      }) 
      fixedDeck = importCards.filter(card => !missingCards.includes(card.name))
      console.log('LESS THAN', fixedDeck.length,  missingCards.length)
      importDeckFinal(fixedDeck, setCurrentDeck, countObj) 
      setDeckIsReady(false) 
      setDeckLength(0) 
      setCountObj({})
    }
    if ((importCards.length > deckLength || importCards.length === deckLength)  && deckIsReady) {
      fixedDeck = []
      importCards.forEach(card => {
        if (card.name in countObj) fixedDeck.push(card)
      })
      console.log('EQUAL', fixedDeck);
      importDeckFinal(fixedDeck, setCurrentDeck, countObj) 
      setDeckIsReady(false) 
      setDeckLength(0) 
      setCountObj({})
    }
  })
  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        variant="outlined"
        color="primary"
        component="label"
        onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
        className={classes.importButton}>
        Import
        </Button>
        <DropzoneDialog
        acceptedFiles={["text/*"]}
        cancelButtonText={"cancel"}
        submitButtonText={"submit"}
        maxFileSize={5000000}
        open={open}
        onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
        onSave={(files) => {
            
            importDeck(
            files,
            setDeckIsReady,
            setDeckLength,
            setCountObj,
            subscription,
            setSubscription,
            setIsReady
            );
          setOpen(false);
          }}
        showPreviews={true}
        showFileNamesInPreview={true}
        />
    </div>
  )
}

export default withTracker(props => {
  const cards = Cards.find({}, { sort: {name: 1}}).fetch();
  const uniqueNames = _.uniq(cards.map(function(x) {return x.name;}), true)
  return {
    importCards: uniqueNames.map(name => cards.find(({ name: cName }) => cName === name))
  };
})(DeckImport);
```

Specifically, deckIsReady is being set to True when only a portion of the data is acutally ready.

Comment: You can use method to fetch the data from the server. The logic is simpler than using subscriptions and better performance.

Answer (score 1):

You cam use two things

- `useTracker` React hook which is part of `meteor-react-data`. This hook re-runs whenever a reactive data source changes.
- use the `Subscription.ready()` to determine if a data source is ready to be consumed.

Put it together something like:

```
const importReady = useTracker(() => Meteor.subscribe('cardSearchTwo').ready())
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm more familiar with the normal meteor subscribe/publish logic, not exactly sure how the react logic you have affects things.

With that said `const subscription = Meteor.subscribe('cardSearchTwo', Object.keys(countObj), {onReady() {setDeckIsReady(true)}})` this line gets re-run multiple times and in the callback you are just setting the expectations that the deck is ready, but then outside of the callback you are setting the deck length and other things related to the subscription you just did - this means that those lines will happen before that subscription has finished getting the data from the publish function.

So the solution here is to put those things related to the deck in the callback so they can be set correctly, then at the end trigger the reactive `DeckImport` by calling `setDeckIsReady(true)`.